# Mikhlin multiplier theorem

Tags: fourier-analysis, proof-explanation, lp-spaces, harmonic-analysis

The Mikhlin multiplier states the following:

Let $m : \mathbb{R}^{n} \backslash \{0\} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ satisfy the following:

$$|\partial^{\alpha}m(\xi)|\leq C_{0}|\xi|^{-|\alpha|}, \forall \alpha \in \mathbb{N}_{0}^{n} \text{ i.e. alpha is a multi-index with }  |\alpha| \leq n+2.$$ $$\text{ Then, for all } 1 < p < \infty, \exists B=B(m,n,p) > 0 \text{ such that } ||T_{m}f||_{L^{p}} \leq B||f||_{L^{p}}, \forall f \in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^{n}).$$

In proving this one considers a partition of unity as follows $\Psi \in C_{c}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^{n}),$ with support of $\Psi \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n} \backslash \{0\}$ and $ \sum_{j=- \infty}^{\infty} \Psi(\frac{x}{2^{j}}) =1 \,\forall x \neq 0$. This can be choosen radial and non-negative.

Then defining $\Psi_{j}(x):= \Psi(\frac{x}{2^{j}})$ for $\Psi$ as above and observing that each $\Psi_{j}$ is supported in a dyadic annulus of size $2^{j}$ and given $j \in \mathbb{Z}, m_{j}(\xi):=\Psi_{j}(\xi)m(\xi)$

**How  the The Fourier multiplier of the above $m_{j}(\xi)$ is $m_{j}(D)$** 
**How do we obtain $m(D)f = \sum_{j}m_{j}(D)f$ with convergence in $L^{2}$ (I know we have to use Plancherel and the Dominated Convergence Theorem somehow)**

Comment: Who is the operator $T_m$?

Comment: @Hugocito Given a function $m : \mathbb{R}^{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ the operator $(T_{m}f)(x):= \int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}m(\xi)f^{\hat{}}(\xi)e^{2 \pi i x \xi}d \xi$ where $f \in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ 

For ease of notation we denote $T_{m} = m(D) $

Comment: As your hints say: Use the Plancherel theorem to express both $m(D)f$ and the sum of the $m_i(D) f$ as functions in the frequency domain. By the identity $\sum_j \Psi(x 2^j) = 1$ you have pointwise convergence, Use the dominated convergence theorem to pass from a pointwise limit to a integral one.

Comment: @AdriánGonzález-Pérez I've had an attempt although I'm not very confident with these calculations yet.

Comment: @AdriánGonzález-Pérez I've had an attempt although I'm not very confident with these calculations yet.

So $m(D)f = \int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}} m(\xi)f^{\hat{}}(\xi)e^{2 \pi i x \xi}d \xi$
$ m_{j}(D)f = \int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}m_{j}(\xi)f^{\hat{}}(\xi)e^{2 \pi i x \xi}d \xi
 = \int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}} \Psi_{j}(\xi)m(\xi)f^{\hat{}}(\xi)e^{2 \pi i x \xi}d \xi
= \int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}} m(\xi)f^{\hat{}}(\xi)e^{2 \pi i x \xi}d \xi$

Therefore $m(D)f = \sum_{j}m_{j}(D)f$

For the convergence I need to use the $L^{p}$ version of the dominated convergence theorem with $p=2.$

Comment: @AdriánGonzález-Pérez if i take the sequence of measurable functions to be the $\Psi_{j}(x):= \Psi(\frac{x}{2^{j}}).$ I'm not sure how to find an explicit $L^{2}$ function that dominates for all of them. Once I've found that then using the result of DCT in $L^{p}$ space for $p=2$ we can then say that the convergence is in $L^{2}$?

Apologies I've often found DCT difficult to apply in $L^{p}$ situations.

Comment: Well, you are not sure howto find a measurable function that dominates all of the $m(\xi) \Psi(2^{j} \xi)  \hat{f}(\xi)$, hint: $\Psi(\xi) \leq 1$.

Comment: @AdriánGonzález-Pérez So i could take for example $e.$ What I wasn't sure on is even though we know the sum of all of the $\Phi_{j} = 1$ how do we know that the dominating function that we pick will hold for each $\Phi_{j}$ individually?

Answer (score 2):

As you mentioned, we can first apply Plancherel's theorem to work in the frequency variable.  We now need to show that 
$$m(\xi) \hat{f}(\xi) = \sum_j m_j(\xi) \hat{f}(\xi).$$
Since $\sum_j m_j(\xi)$ converges to $m(\xi)$ pointwise a.e., it suffices to show that $\sum_j m_j(\xi) \hat{f}(\xi)$ is bounded pointwise by some $L^2$ function.  Now, by the decay assumption on $m$, $m \in L^\infty$, so $m(\xi) \hat{f} \in L^2$.  Since the $m_j$ are nonnegative and sum to $m$ pointwise, it follows that
$$\sum_{j = -N}^N m_j \hat{f} \leq m\hat{f}\qquad \text{a.e.}$$
so since $m\hat{f} \in L^2$, we can conclude.

Comment: thanks, that makes sense. One quick question. Why is it that since $m \in L^{\infty}$ this means that $m(\xi)f^{\hat{}} \in L^{2}$?

Comment: This is Holder's inequality: $\lVert m\hat{f} \rVert_{L^2} \leq \lVert m \rVert_{L^\infty}\lVert \hat{f} \rVert_{L^2}$

Comment: But isn't Holder's inequality $||fg||_{L^{1}} \leq ||f||_{L^{p}} ||g||_{L^{q}}, \frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{q} = 1$

Comment: There is a generalization, see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hölder%27s_inequality.

Comment: Alternatively, just note that $|m\hat{f}| \leq \lVert m \rVert_{L^\infty}\hat{f}$ almost everywhere.